# Moq Unit Test - Multiple Post Method failing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, moq

I have written Unit test case for ASP.NET CORE MVC Application. The function has has multiple post method and ONE Get method. 1st Post method injects correctly and test passes successfully, however the second Post method is always NULL and does not inject successful, but the previous Get & Post operation is successful.

This line is not getting injected correctly.

```
_WebService.Setup(test => test.PostRequestAsync<CommonResultDTO>(Constants.SendVerificationCodeAPI, customViewModel)).ReturnsAsync(deserialisedObj);
```

Return value of this call is always null.

```
var externalApiOutput = await _webService.PostRequestAsync<CommonResultDTO>(Constants.SendVerificationCodeAPI, newModel);  // this value is returning null
```

### MVC Controller

```
public class AccountController
{

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;   
    public AccountController(IHttpContextAccessor accessor
        , IWebService webService) 

    {
        _accessor = accessor;            
        _webService = webService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.Email = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Email) ? model.Email.ToLowerInvariant() : string.Empty;
            var result = await _webService.PostRequestAsync<CommonResultDTO>(Constants.UserLoginAPI, model);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDto>(result.Object.ToString());

                if (output != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(output.Email))
                {
                    var userRoleInfo = await _webService.GetRequestAsync<List<UserRoleViewModel>>(string.Format(Constants.GetUserRoleInfoAPI, output.Email));                       
                    if (userRoleInfo != null)
                    {
                        var claims = new List<Claim>
                        {
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, output.Email),
                            new Claim("Username", output.UserName),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Convert.ToString(userRoleInfo.FirstOrDefault().Name))
                        };

                        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = model.RememberMe });

                        if (output.TwoFactorEnabled)
                        {
                            var newModel = sendVerificationCode(output.PhoneNumber, Constants.CountryCodeValue);
                            var externalApiOutput = await _webService.PostRequestAsync<CommonResultDTO>(Constants.SendVerificationCodeAPI, newModel);  // this value is returning null

                            // value of "externalApiOutput " is null, hence the further cases are failing.  
                            if (externalApiOutput != null && externalApiOutput.Succeeded == true)
                            {
                                return RedirectToAction("Login_2FA");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home");
                        }
                    }
                }


                return View(new LoginViewModel());
            }
            else
            {                 
                ShowMessage(MessageType.warning.ToString(), Constants.InvalidCredential);
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    private CustomViewModel sendVerificationCode(string toPhoneNumber, string countryCode)
    {
        var externalModel = new CustomViewModel();

        ExternalAPIService externalService = new ExternalAPIService(_settings);
        externalModel = externalService.GetOtherSettings();

        externalModel.ToPhoneNumber = toPhoneNumber;
        externalModel.CountryCode = countryCode;

        return externalModel;

    }

}
```

### Unit Test

```
public class AccountControllerTest : TestFixture
{
    public AccountControllerTest()
    {

        _accessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        _WebService = new Mock<IWebService>();


        var authServiceMock = new Mock<IAuthenticationService>();
        authServiceMock
            .Setup(_ => _.SignInAsync(It.IsAny<HttpContext>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<ClaimsPrincipal>(), It.IsAny<AuthenticationProperties>()))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult((object)null));

        var serviceProviderMock = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();
        serviceProviderMock
            .Setup(_ => _.GetService(typeof(IAuthenticationService)))
            .Returns(authServiceMock.Object);

        var urlHelperFactory = new Mock<IUrlHelperFactory>();
        serviceProviderMock
            .Setup(s => s.GetService(typeof(IUrlHelperFactory)))
            .Returns(urlHelperFactory.Object);

        var context = new DefaultHttpContext() {
            RequestServices = serviceProviderMock.Object
        };
        _accessor.Setup(_ => _.HttpContext).Returns(context);


        Mock<ITempDataDictionary> tempData = new Mock<ITempDataDictionary>();

        accountController = new AccountController(_accessor.Object, _WebService.Object)
        {
            ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
            {
                HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
                {
                    // How mock RequestServices?
                    RequestServices = serviceProviderMock.Object

                }
            }
            , TempData =tempData.Object
        };

    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task LoginTest_Post_UserHasValidCredentialsAndRoleAndTwoFactor() // this method is failing, hence commented out for time-being
    {
        // Arrange

        var mockModel = new LoginViewModel { };
        mockModel.Email = "test@test.com";
        mockModel.Password = "test123";
        mockModel.RememberMe = false;

        var customViewModel  = new CustomViewModel()
        {           
            ToPhoneNumber = "7009529018",       
            CountryCode = "91"          
        };


        var commonResult = new CommonResultDTO { Object = User(), Succeeded = true, StatusCode = Common.Enums.ResponseStatusCodeEnum.Success };
        var email = User().Email;
        string stringObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(commonResult);
        var deserialisedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CommonResultDTO>(stringObj);

        var output = GetUserRole();

        _WebService.Setup(test => test.PostRequestAsync<CommonResultDTO>(Constants.UserLoginAPI, mockModel)).ReturnsAsync(deserialisedObj);
        _WebService.Setup(test => test.GetRequestAsync<List<UserRoleViewModel>>(string.Format(Constants.GetUserRoleInfoAPI, email))).ReturnsAsync(output);

        // this method is not injecting correctly and the value is alwasy NULL
        _WebService.Setup(test => test.PostRequestAsync<CommonResultDTO>(Constants.SendVerificationCodeAPI, customViewModel)).ReturnsAsync(deserialisedObj);

        var result = await accountController.Login(mockModel);

        var redirectResult = result as RedirectToActionResult;

        Assert.NotNull(redirectResult);
        Assert.Equal("Home", redirectResult.ControllerName);
        Assert.Equal("Dashboard", redirectResult.ActionName);

    }
}
```

Please suggest how can get this working.

Comment: Where is `twilioModel` in the example?

Comment: @Nkosi, apologies, it was incorrect model, its actualy "newModel". Have correct the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the arguments used in setup do not match what was passed while exercising the test the mock will return the default value of the return type. In this case *null*.

You can loosen the match by using `It.IsAny<T>()` if the value of the argument is of no concern

```
_WebService
    .Setup(_ => _.PostRequestAsync<CommonResultDTO>(Constants.SendVerificationCodeAPI, It.IsAny<CustomViewModel>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(deserialisedObj);
```

Comment: thanks for support, solution worked for me like Charm!. Have question regarding the value passed (mock object and real object)both are of same type i.e. CustomViewModel, then how come it is not of same type. Its Just like as previous post method call.

Comment: @Arayn they are not the same **instance**, that is why they did not match. You example used raw values and not argument matchers.

Comment: You can use it.is to check certain properties of the model passed in have the expected values.